# attr_protected equivalent for Rails 6? gem protected_attributes needs activemodel < 5.0 and hence is not compatible for rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, attr-protected

Searching for an 'attr_protected' equivalent for Rails 6

gem protected_attributes which served the purpose from rails 4 onwards, needs activemodel < 5.0 and hence is not solving for rails 6.

Any alternatives or better solution for achieving the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this gem

```
gem 'protected_attributes_continued'
```

This gem adds the class methods `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected` to declare white or black lists of attributes.

More info click [here](https://github.com/westonganger/protected_attributes_continued)